# How to create a post with next buttons

Tags: plugins

I am trying to create a post to show top 10 movies of 2013.

I have created a post with the same heading. However how can I show the post with next buttons. That is position 10 movie should be first, with corresponding image and some text.

Then on clicking next button go to 9th movie.  like that the last screen should be the 1st movie.

Is there any plugins available? or how can I achieve it.

Comment: You mean you want single post navigation for one specific category named videos?

Comment: Please explain what you are doing in more detail. What are you movies? A CPT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress has [Page-Links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Page-Links) links feature that allows to easily and natively split single post into multiple pages.

The pages are separated using `<!--nextpage-->` tag and normally theme should automatically handle output, using [`wp_link_pages()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_link_pages/) template tag.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) It did the trick :) I will Up vote Once I have enough point :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need a plugin to do this.

Just put this code into your while loop in single.php, if you could not find it, put in index.php. Put after the_content(); or wherever you want the link appears.

```
<?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
```